# Paracompact and Normal spaces

Tags: general-topology

Lemma: Let $X$ be a paracompact space. Let $A,B$ two closed subset of $X$ such that $A \cap B=\emptyset$. If $\forall x \in B$ there exists disjoint open sets $U_x$ and $V_x$ such that $A\subseteq U_x$ and $x \in V_x$, then there exists disjoint open set $U$ and $V$ such that $A\subseteq U$ and $B \subseteq V$.

**Proof:**

The open cover $\{X\setminus B\}\cup\{V_x: x \in B\}$ of $X$ has locally finite open refinement $\{W_\gamma\mid \gamma \in \Gamma\}$.

Let $Γ_1=\{\gamma \in \Gamma: W_\gamma \subseteq V_x  \,\text{for some}\, x\in B\}$.

Since $x \notin \bigcup_{\gamma \in Γ_1} W_\gamma \implies x\notin w_γ,∋γ∈Γ_1⟶ x∉v_x,∀x∈B⟶ x∉B$, then $B⊆⋃_{γ∈Γ_1} w_γ$.

---

I am trying to understand the first part of this proof. I am stuck at this part $x∉w_γ,∋γ∈Γ_1⟶ x∉v_x,∀x∈B$ because $w_γ⊆v_x$ so why is $x∉w_γ,∋γ∈Γ_1⟶ x∉v_x,∀x∈B$ true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author wants to show that $$B \subseteq \bigcup_{\gamma \in \Gamma_1} W_\gamma\tag{1}$$

So take $x \in B$. This is covered by some $W_\gamma$ (so $x \in W_\gamma$ for some $\gamma \in \Gamma$) (from the fact that the $W_\gamma$ cover $X$). This $W_\gamma$ is not a subset of $X\setminus B$ (as witnessed by $x$ itself) and as it *is* a refinement of the unnamed used cover, we must have that it is a subset of $V_p$ for some $p \in B$ by definition. This then shows that by definition in fact $\gamma \in \Gamma_1$ and so the inclusion $(1)$ has been shown. We use nothing but the definitions and common sense.

IMO all these strange formulaic notation that you or your text is using just obscures these straightforward facts. Just reason logically and more importantly, **write natural language**.

As to the text argument write-up:
There are two types of $\gamma$: those such that $W_\gamma$ is contained in *some* $V_x, x \in B$ **or** those whose $W_\gamma$ is contained in $X\setminus B$; $\Gamma_1$ collects those of the first type. So if $x \notin \bigcup_{\gamma \in \Gamma_1} W_\gamma$, it must be covered by **some** $W_\gamma$ (they form a cover of $X$) and by assumption is not of the first type. Hence $\gamma \notin \Gamma_1$. So $x \in W_\gamma \subseteq X\setminus B$ and so $x \notin B$. The proof's intermediate claim that $x$ is in none of the $V_y, y \in B$ is nonsense, it could very well be in one (say if it's outside $B$ but "close" to it). The claim is unnecessary for the final inclusion which we do need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still don't get it. I mean why is it that if $x \notin \bigcup_{\gamma \in Γ_1} W_\gamma$ then $x \notin V_x,\forall x$. I mean if $x\notin F$ and $F\subseteq G$. Then that doesn't necessarily mean $x\notin G$.

Comment: @Isaac I added some comments about that.

Comment: Makes sense now. Thank you.

Comment: Just one last thought. Since $V_x$ is allowed to intersect $X\setminus B$. Then what if this $x$ which belongs to $X\setminus B$ now also belongs to this intersection. Hence $x$ is in some $V_x$. Wouldn't that make the statement that $x\notin V_x,\forall x\in B$ False?

Comment: @Isaac that statement isn’t used at all. Forget about it. You only need that $x \notin B$.

Comment: Does the prove assume that $B^c\cap (\cup\{V_x: x \in B\})=\phi$?

Comment: @Isaac No that need not be true. It's also not needed.

Comment: I understand that if $x \notin \bigcup_{\gamma \in \Gamma_1} W_\gamma$ then $x\notin B$. What I don't understand is why is it true that $x\notin V_x,\forall x\in B$? Suppose that $x$ is in **some** $W_\gamma$ of the second type .i.e. $W_\gamma\subseteq B^c$. Then it maybe still true that this  $W_\gamma$ intersects some $V_x$ and $x$ may be contained in this intersection. Hence $x$ belongs in some $V_x$. I hope you understand my confusion.

Comment: @Isaac that statement in the proof is just false. Ignore it.

Comment: You mean the $x∉V_x,∀x∈B$ statement?

Comment: @Isaac yes. It’s not  needed.

Comment: Yes, it didn't look right to me. Thanks.